# Dropdown sub menu not showing as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sub menu in a html navigation menu. The menu is appearing but it is showing in the menu list instead of to the right. I have made a screenshot of the problem and would be grateful if someone could help me adapt my code.

You will see from the screenshot, that the sub menu is appearing in the main menu and not off to the right of the selected link.

I have tried so many options that I need to turn to the experts for help.
Many thanks

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #0c323f;
  position: static;
}

.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navigation li {
  float: left;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background: #1a4655;
}

.navigation li:first-child {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -3px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: none;
}

.navigation li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  background: #1a4655;
  /*          border: solid 3px #fff;*/
  border-top: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
}

.navigation li:hover>ul li:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.navigation li li a:hover {
  background: #0c323f;
  color: white;
}

.navigation ul li:last-child a,
.navigation ul li:last-child a:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="/domain/admin/index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/domain/admin/test.php" title="Requests">Requests</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" title="Boxes">Boxes</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="Files">Files</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Recycle">Recycle</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Box Supply">Box Supply</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" title="Files">Files</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Recycle">Recycle</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Box Supply">Box Supply</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Recycle">Recycle</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Destruction">Destruction</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Destruction Schedules">Destruction Schedules</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="Reports">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Invoices">Invoices</a></li>
    <li><a href="/domain/admin/cp.php" title="Control Panel">Control Panel</a></li>
    <li><a href="/domain/admin/logout.php" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Image screenshot

Normal dropdown

[image: Normal dropdown]

Sub menu showing problem

[image: sub menu showing problem]

Comment: The code you posted looks like this --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/s3cd7a1z/ --> is there more css you could add to make a complete demo? Also, when you say that it should appear to the right, could you describe or post an image of the intended layout? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `top:0` and `left:100%` to the 2nd level submenu

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #0c323f;
  position: static;
}

.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navigation li {
  float: left;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background: #1a4655;
}

.navigation li:first-child {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -3px;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: none;
}

.navigation li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  background: #1a4655;
  /*          border: solid 3px #fff;*/
  border-top: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
}

.navigation li:hover>ul li:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.navigation li li a:hover {
  background: #0c323f;
  color: white;
}

.navigation ul li:last-child a,
.navigation ul li:last-child a:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="/domain/admin/index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/domain/admin/test.php" title="Requests">Requests</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" title="Boxes">Boxes</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="Files">Files</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Recycle">Recycle</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Box Supply">Box Supply</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" title="Files">Files</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Recycle">Recycle</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Box Supply">Box Supply</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Recycle">Recycle</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Destruction">Destruction</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Destruction Schedules">Destruction Schedules</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="Reports">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Invoices">Invoices</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent. thanks very much. As a side note how do i remove the border-bottom-left-radius from the sub menu. I have tried various options but not have much luck. many thanks

Comment: @user1532468 Try `border-bottom-left-radius:0`

Comment: That would be in this code right? thanks .navigation ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

Comment: thanks. Problem I am having with sub menu. When i click link in menu the sub goes to the top and not aligned with the selected link This is a problem if there are only say 2 items in the sub, you cannot select as the menu goes to the top. is there a way to align the sub with the selected link. thanks

Comment: @user1532468 sorry to say but its not clear what you are asking....I will suggest you to ask a new question to find out what is the issue...

Comment: if you layout the code you will see that if you select say item 3 in main menu which the sub menu has 2 items, then you cannot select the items because they are at the top so when you move the mouse to select the menu dissapers. thanks

Comment: to try and make it clear. if you modify the code in your answer so that recycle has 2 links. The problem should then be obvious. thanks

Comment: which recycle you are talking about